# Iterating uniformly over std::vector<T> and std::vector<unique_ptr<T>>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I commonly face the situation where I introduce an abstract base class (call it `Foo`) to store instances of different child classes (call them `Bar` and `Baz`) in a container (e.g., `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`). For the sake of illustration, let me put these sample classes here:

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual int getId() const = 0;
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    Bar(int id) : id_(id) {}
    int getId() const override { return id_; }
private:
    int id_;
};

class Baz : public Foo {
public:
    Baz(int id) : id_(id) {}
    int getId() const override { return id_; }
private:
    int id_;
};
```

If I implement a function to iterate over `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`, it looks like

```
template<class InputIterator>
void printIds(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        std::cout << (*first)->getId() << std::endl;
}
```

But what if I also want to allow iterating over vectors of **homogeneous** type (e.g., `std::vector<Bar>`) without rewriting the whole function (or possible others, of similar type)? I see two obvious possibilities:

1) Implement functions

```
template<class Type>
const Type & dereference(const Type &value) {
    return value;
}

template<class Type>
const Type & dereference(const std::unique_ptr<Type> &value) {
    return *value;
}
```

and replace

```
std::cout << (*first)->getId() << std::endl;
```

by

```
std::cout << dereference(*first).getId() << std::endl;
```

2) Implement functions

```
template<class Type>
int getId(const Type &value) {
    return value.getId();
}

template<class Type>
int getId(const std::unique_ptr<Type> &value) {
    return value->getId();
}
```

and replace

```
std::cout << (*first)->getId() << std::endl;
```

by

```
std::cout << getId(*first) << std::endl;
```

Option 1) seems like a general possibility to treat references of type `Type &` (or `const Type &`) and `std::unique_ptr<Type>` (or even `Type *` or `const Type *`) uniformly. However, I have not seen this being much used in production code. Is this a common pattern to avoid code duplication? Or are there better ways to handle this?

Comment: "*Is this a common pattern to avoid code duplication?*" No, because people generally don't need to take a function that iterates over a container of pointers and then make it iterate over a container of non-pointers.

Comment: My answer would have been to use option 1. create a "get" function which has overloads to deal with both value and pointer-like types.

Comment: Have you considerd an indirecting iterator wrapper e.g. [boost::indirect_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html)?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes you are.  The OP wants to uniformly iterate over the *pointed to* elements in a container of pointers and a container of items.

Comment: I doubt it is actually important for you to have the same code for the two kinds of iteration. Are you sure you're not trying to micro-optimize here just because it "feels right" as opposed to standing to gain something meaningful? And see what @NicolBolas said.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok, it might not be a *common* problem, which I described, but I think there are indeed some situations where it proves useful to have a function accept both variants. I think the `boost::indirect_iterator` proposed by @ecatmur is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write `get_ptr<T>`.

`get_ptr<T*>` returns nullptr if it fails.

If passed a reference to something convertible to `T*`, it returns it.

If passed a reference to something convertible to `T&`, it returns a pointer to it.

Otherwise, if passed a pointer, it returns null if the pointer is null and `get_ptr<T>(*ptr)` if the pointer it not null.

Otherwise, if `x.get()` returns a pointer, it returns `get_ptr<T>(x.get())`.

Now `printIds` reads:

```
template<class InputIterator>
void printIds(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
  for (; first != last; ++first)
    std::cout << get_ptr<Foo>(*first)->getId() << std::endl;
}
```

note that the possiblity of `get_ptr` failing is rather explicit here.

---

If you don't want to hardcode the type `T`, we could go a step further.

If `get_obj_ptr` is passed a pointer to a pointer, and the pointer is not null, it dereference the pointer and recurses.  If it is null, it returns nullptr cast to the same type.

If passed a class for whom `.get()` returns a pointer, it recurses on `get_obj_ptr(x.get())`.

Otherwise, if `get_obj_ptr(x)` is passed a pointer, it returns `x`.

Otherwise, if `get_obj_ptr(x)` is passed an lvalue, it returns `std::addressof(x)`.

Unlike your code, it admits the possiblity of failure.

```
template<class InputIterator>
void printIds(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
  for (; first != last; ++first)
    auto* ptr = get_obj_ptr(*first);
    if (ptr)
      std::cout << ptr->getId() << std::endl;
    else
      std::cout << "null object" << std::endl;
}
```

---

As a general rule, taking smart pointers and assuming they are never null is a bad idea.

Comment: I think that, in general, this comes close to what I had in mind with the `dereference` function in my question. Yet, you're right that this won't work in case that the smart pointer points to null. In such situations, your approach certainly is the better one; I'll accept this as an answer.